# Pivot Data w/ same ID's in SQL and create 0's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data in the format:

```
id    speed     power
1     2        100
1     3        250
1     4        310
2     1        90
2     2        140
2     3        210
```

and need to pivot it and create 0 values for where there doesn't exist a corresponding speed value (there is no speed = 1 for id = 1 but there is id = 2 ) :

```
id   1     2     3     4
1    0     100   250   310
2    90    140   210   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #Test (id int,    speed int,     power int)
Insert #Test Values (1,     2,        100)
Insert #Test Values (1,     3,        250)
Insert #Test Values (1,     4,        310)
Insert #Test Values (2,     1,        90)
Insert #Test Values (2,     2,        140)
Insert #Test Values (2,     3,        210)

Select  IsNull([1],0),IsNull([2],0),
        IsNull([3],0),IsNull([4],0) 
    From #Test 
    Pivot (Sum(Power) 
        For Speed In ([1],[2],[3],[4])) As PivotPowers
```

Results:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)

    0   100 250 310
    90  140 210 0
```

Comment: this returns all 6 rows, with the power values forming an ordered diagonal; i'm seeking to return one row per id, with the powers as the values and speeds as the columns.

Comment: I will post the output of my query above.  Seems to work fine for me...

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using SQL Server 2014. Unfortunately, I can't replicate your results